# I am getting mysql error check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 4

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am getting my sql error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 4

SELECT cm.user_id, chat_message_content, u.firstname FROM chat_message cm JOIN user u ON cm.user_id = u.user_id WHERE cm.chat_id= ?"

Model

```
function get_chat_messages($chat_id) {
        $query_str = "SELECT cm.user_id, chat_message_content, u.firstname
                      FROM chat_message cm
                      JOIN user u ON cm.user_id = u.user_id
                      WHERE cm.chat_id= ?";
        $results = $this->db->query($query_str, $chat_id);
        return $results;
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing more about your DB class, it's hard to say for certain; but the syntax error suggests that your placeholder isn't being handled properly (i.e. the database is receiving a literal `?`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting quotes around your question mark if it's the value in the database you're filtering by:

```
$query_str = "SELECT cm.user_id, chat_message_content, u.firstname
                      FROM chat_message cm
                      JOIN user u ON cm.user_id = u.user_id
                      WHERE cm.chat_id= '?'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$query_str = "SELECT cm.user_id, chat_message_content, u.firstname
                      FROM chat_message cm
                      JOIN user u ON cm.user_id = u.user_id
                      WHERE cm.chat_id= (?)";
```